# Using elements of a list in different parts of the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm very new to Python and thus have a (probably very stupid) question:
I have a list with different numbers that I want to use in different parts of the code. However, every number should only be used once and in the same order as they occur in the list. I'm not sure how to realize that. I was thinking about adding a big loop around the code that iterates through the list, but that would be not very elegant as the code is quite long and also I'm not sure if that would even work. 
Basically, what I want to do is check at different parts of the code if the list item fulfills a certain condition or not (followed by executing a function if it does). This is one example that should check if one item of the list 'TargetRand' fulfills a specific condition:

```
TargetRand= [1,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]
WordList = ["dog", "cat", "frog", "mouse", "chicken", "penguin"]
WordList2 = ["tomato", "cucumber", "apple", "carrot", "cheese", "bread"]
WordList3 = ["car", "bike", "shoe", "board", "wheel", "door"]

def SwapWord1():
   swap= TargetRand[x]
   print(swap) #debug check
   if swap == 1:
       a= list(range(1,6))
       m= random.choice(a)
       WordList[m] = "target"
   print(WordList) #debug check

def SwapWord2():
   swap= TargetRand[x]
   print(swap) #debug check
   if swap == 2:
       a= list(range(1,6))
       m= random.choice(a)
       WordList2[m] = "target"
   print(WordList2) #debug check

def SwapWord3():
   swap= TargetRand[x]
   print(swap) #debug check
   if swap == 3:
       a= list(range(1,6))
       m= random.choice(a)
       WordList3[m] = "target"
   print(WordList3) #debug check
```

The 'x' should then be the respective item of the list. This is just a simplified part of the code where the list items are used, there will be other parts where the next item should be checked. Overall, the list contains about 70 items that should be checked consecutively in the order of the list in different parts of the code.

I'm really confused, how to realize that and in desperate need of some ideas! I'm sorry that I could not provide more solution approaches.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: There you go. This is not my original code, but it would be too long and unnecessarily complex (also my lists are excel files that are read in).

Comment: Your code does not make a lot of sense to me. First of all, it's not hard to rewriting it to one function. Whenever you create a function with numbers behind it, start realizing you are doing something wrong. Especially when you have so much duplicate code. And X is probaly a random, however with that random, you select a random number in a list of 6 numbers with no duplicates.. Creating a random to create a random is a step too much..

Comment: I see your point. Actually, these are different functions that contain individual lists with different kinds of stimuli (auditory, images, words) and are part of functions that play those stimuli, so it makes more sense why they are separated. I created the list TargetRand with a randomization function (with certain conditions) in another file and imported it. This list is used to determine whether an element will be swapped or not (it actually just contains 0s and 1s). Maybe this is not the best way to code this, but as I mentioned I am very new to coding and just started last week.

Comment: "This is just a simplified part of the code where the list items are used, there will be other parts where the next item should be checked." -> Sorry, I missed this part. You could create a class to store all your data into an instance of that class. You could create a basic class and the other classes can extend these functions. You said you just started, do you mean with python or programming?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but "every number should only be used once and in the same order as they occur in the list" makes me think you could use [pop()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), especially because you already have a list put together. When not given an argument, it will return the last element and remove it from the list.

Popping the first element would look like this:

```
>>> TargetRand = [1,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]
>>> x = TargetRand.pop(0)
>>> print(x)
1
>>> print(TargetRand)
[2,3,2,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]
```

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You say: "I was thinking about adding a big loop around the code that iterates through the list, but that would be not very elegant as the code is quite long"

That's why we define functions. All of programming is breaking things down into smaller steps that make sense, where they are coded. You will never view and understand the entire program at once.

```
def DoStuffWithNumber(x):
    # all your code here
    ...

# set up data/lists here
...

# put a loop around them here with two lines of code
for x in TargetRand:
    DoStuffWithNumber(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how could I manage that each function in this big loop is getting another item than the previous one and not just the list item that is currently iterated?

Comment: It doesn't even see TargetRand. It just uses x, which we have taken from the list and passed as a parameter.

Comment: But does it not use the same x for in one iteration for all the functions? I want to use each x just once and move to the next.
I was thinking about using x as the parameter for the first function, x+1 in the r the second and x+2 in the third function, but then then the iteration would have to start with x+2 the next time in order to not repeat list items.

Comment: @Pythonymus I believe my answer covers that use case.

Comment: Oh I did not see it! I'll try it out, thank you so much!